# Quando digito 1 ele não faz as perguntas dnv, e não consigo arrumar isso

Tags: c++

Quando o usuário escolhe continuar *(opção `1`)* não esta aparecendo para digitar os lados do triângulo novamente

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{   
    int x, y ,z, o;
    
    printf ("Informe o valor do primeiro lado: ");
    scanf ("%i", &x);
    printf ("Informe o valor do segundo lado: ");
    scanf ("%i", &y);
    printf ("Informe o valor do terceiro lado: ");
    scanf ("%i", &z);

    if ( x == y && x == z)
    {
        printf ("Esse é um triângulo EQUILÁTERO.");
    }
    else if ( x == y && x != z || x == z && x != y){
        printf ("Esse é um triângulo ISÓSCELES.");
    }
    else if ( x != y && x != z && y != z){
        printf ("Esse é um triângulo ESCALENO.");
    }
    
    while (o != 2){
        printf ("\nDigite 1 para CONTINUAR \nDigite 2 para SAIR");
        scanf ("%i", &o);
    }
    system ("pause");
}
```

Comment: Qual é o problema?

Comment: Quando o usuário digitar 1 para continuar, não aparece as opções para ele digitir o valor dos do triângulo...

Comment: é duro não tenho como testar

Answer (score 0):

Dentro do `while` não tem perguntas

```
while (o != 2){
   printf ("\nDigite 1 para CONTINUAR \nDigite 2 para SAIR");
   scanf ("%i", &o);
}
```

Você tem que coloca seu *'digitar os lados do triângulo'* dentro do `while`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
 
int main(){
 
    int x, y ,z, o;
 
    while (o != 2){  /// ; verifica se continua
        printf ("Informe o valor do primeiro lado: ");
        scanf ("%i", &x);
        printf ("Informe o valor do segundo lado: ");
        scanf ("%i", &y);
        printf ("Informe o valor do terceiro lado: ");
        scanf ("%i", &z);
 
        if ( x == y && x == z){
            printf ("Esse é um triângulo EQUILÁTERO.");
        }
        else if ( (x == y && x != z) || (x == z && x != y) ){
            printf ("Esse é um triângulo ISÓSCELES.");
        }
        else
        if ( x != y && x != z && y != z){
            printf ("Esse é um triângulo ESCALENO.");
        }
        printf ("\nDigite 1 para CONTINUAR \nDigite 2 para SAIR");
        scanf ("%i", &o);

    } /// ; fim do loop
    system ("pause");
}
```

<sup>Veja o código funcionando no [repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/CompetentSpeedyCharacters)</sup>

Agora note que o `while` já começa verificando se ele deve entrar no loop. Como na sua logica ele tem que entrar no `while` pelo menos 1 vez uma melhor opção seria usar o `do-while` que faz essa checagem no final do loop, veja o código abaixo:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
 
int main(){
 
    int x, y ,z, o;
 
    do{  /// ; inicio do loop
        printf ("Informe o valor do primeiro lado: ");
        scanf ("%i", &x);
        printf ("Informe o valor do segundo lado: ");
        scanf ("%i", &y);
        printf ("Informe o valor do terceiro lado: ");
        scanf ("%i", &z);
 
        if ( x == y && x == z){
            printf ("Esse é um triângulo EQUILÁTERO.");
        }
        else if ( (x == y && x != z) || (x == z && x != y) ){
            printf ("Esse é um triângulo ISÓSCELES.");
        }
        else
        if ( x != y && x != z && y != z){
            printf ("Esse é um triângulo ESCALENO.");
        }
        printf ("\nDigite 1 para CONTINUAR \nDigite 2 para SAIR");
        scanf ("%i", &o);

    }while (o != 2); /// ; verifica se continua
 
    system ("pause");
}
```

<sup>Veja o código funcionando no [repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/AlphanumericDeepSeptagon)</sup>

> Referencia: [`while`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/while-statement-cpp?view=vs-2019), [`do-while()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/do-while-statement-cpp?view=vs-2019)

Answer (score 0):

Olá, para a lógica funcionar coloque tudo dentro de um do{}while();

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){

int x, y ,z, o;

do{
  printf ("Informe o valor do primeiro lado: ");
  scanf ("%i", &x);
  printf ("Informe o valor do segundo lado: ");
  scanf ("%i", &y);
  printf ("Informe o valor do terceiro lado: ");
  scanf ("%i", &z);
  if ( x == y && x == z){
    printf ("Esse é um triângulo EQUILÁTERO.");
  }
  else 
  if ( (x == y && x != z) || (x == z && x != y)){
   printf ("Esse é um triângulo ISÓSCELES.");
  }
  else
  if ( x != y && x != z && y != z){
   printf ("Esse é um triângulo ESCALENO.");
  }
  printf ("\nDigite 1 para CONTINUAR \nDigite 2 para SAIR");
  scanf ("%i", &o);
 } while (o != 2);
 system ("pause");
 }
```

Comment: não sei onde usar o do{}while

Comment: No código da postagem tem 1 exemplo de utilização.